# How do I provide path to image where asked for path to image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("--image", "-i", required = True, help = "Path to input image")
ap.add_argument("--template", "-t", required = True, help = "Path to template image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

What do I need to execute the code?

I get the following error

> usage: [-h] -i IMAGE -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL -l LABELS : error: the
>   following arguments are required: -i/--image

Is it that I need to get the path to the image where it says help?

Comment: You need to provide an image path. It won't get any more basic than this...

Comment: Im sorry could you provide an example? beacsue im kinda to this i did  ap.add_argument("-i", "--/Home/Desktop/face-detector/images", required=True,... is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
ap.add_argument("--image", "-i", required = True, help = "Path to input image")
```

says that your program is expecting the user to put something like `--image ~/Home/Desktop/face-detector/myimage.png` *on the command line after the name of the program when the program is run*. You're clearly not doing that, which is why you are getting an error message. While you are testing you can put a default value in to save typing the `--image` command line parameter every time:

```
ap.add_argument("--image", "-i", required = True, help = "Path to input image", default="~/Home/Desktop/face-detector/myimage.png")
```

but that is clearly not sensible except for testing.